# making query shorter refined and optimize

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this query which is working fine, but there are repetition (repeating) in it and in every query, values from only "where" statement and "And" statement changes

I am wondering if i can produce the same results by making the below query shorter (less code) or in other words optimize it. Anyone?

```
DECLARE @Queued int;
set @Queued = ( 
            select count(STATENAME)as Queued 
from   [EAC].[MessageStore].[MessageProcessingAttemptState] a inner JOIN 
 [EAC].[MessageStore].[MessageProcessingAttempt]  b
ON a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID = b.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID
inner join [EAC].[MessageStore].[Message] c
 on b.MessageID = c.MessageID
Where a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID = '1'
and c.MessageGroupId = '44'
and b.QueuedTime BETWEEN '2014-09-12' AND '2014-09-16')

Declare @Scheduled int;
set @Scheduled =
(select count(STATENAME)as Scheduled 
from   [EAC].[MessageStore].[MessageProcessingAttemptState] a inner JOIN 
 [EAC].[MessageStore].[MessageProcessingAttempt] b
ON a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID = b.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID
inner join [EACatalog2013].[MessageStore].[Message] c
 on b.MessageID = c.MessageID
WHERE a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID = '2'
and c.MessageGroupId = '44'
and b.QueuedTime BETWEEN '2014-09-12' AND '2014-09-16')

Declare @NotCompleted int;
set @NotCompleted = @Queued + @Scheduled

DECLARE @Queued1 int;

set @Queued1 = ( 
            select count(STATENAME)as Queued 
from   [EAC].[MessageStore].[MessageProcessingAttemptState] a inner JOIN 
 [EAC].[MessageStore].[MessageProcessingAttempt]  b
ON a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID = b.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID
inner join [EACatalog2013].[MessageStore].[Message] c
 on b.MessageID = c.MessageID
Where a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID = '1'
and c.MessageGroupId = '45'
and b.QueuedTime BETWEEN '2014-09-12' AND '2014-09-16')

Declare @Scheduled1 int;
set @Scheduled1 =
(select count(STATENAME)as Scheduled 
from   [EAC].[MessageStore].[MessageProcessingAttemptState] a inner JOIN 
 [EAC].[MessageStore].[MessageProcessingAttempt]  b
ON a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID = b.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID
inner join [EACatalog2013].[MessageStore].[Message] c
 on b.MessageID = c.MessageID
WHERE a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID = '2'
and c.MessageGroupId = '45'
and b.QueuedTime BETWEEN '2014-09-12' AND '2014-09-16')

Declare @NotCompleted1 int;
set @NotCompleted1 = @Queued1 + @Scheduled1

select @NotCompleted as NotCompleted
union
select @NotCompleted1 as NotCompleted
```

Comment: How about a description of what the query does?

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with a simple single row returned, how about this..  It gets one single pass through all the data for either message group 44 or 45, and only the state 1 or 2, within the dates.

by doing a SUM( logical condition ), if the logical condition is true, it counts as 1, else 0.

So, by the condition qualifying both group and state allows a simple 1 row with 4 columns of respective queued and scheduled.  Now, if you need the difference (net) between them, just subtract as needed.

```
SELECT
      SUM( case when c.MessageGroupId = '44' AND a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID = '1' then 1 else 0 end ) as Queued,
      SUM( case when c.MessageGroupId = '44' AND a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as Scheduled,
      SUM( case when c.MessageGroupId = '45' AND a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as Queued1,
      SUM( case when c.MessageGroupId = '45' AND a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as Scheduled1
   from
      [EAC].[MessageStore].[MessageProcessingAttemptState] a 
         inner JOIN [EAC].[MessageStore].[MessageProcessingAttempt] b
            ON a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID = b.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID
            inner join [EAC].[MessageStore].[Message] c
               on b.MessageID = c.MessageID
   Where 
          a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID IN ( '1', '2' )
      and c.MessageGroupId IN ( '44', '45' )
      and b.QueuedTime BETWEEN '2014-09-12' AND '2014-09-16'
```

Comment: this script is giving error in this part   c.MessageGroupId = '44' Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: @user2183213, changed to case/when, give it a try now

Answer (score -1):

I would write one query without the where clause and insert that into a table. Then write 4 short and concise queries to get your actual data. Here is an example for your first two queries.

```
select count(STATENAME)as Queued,
    a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID as MessageProcessingAttemptStateID,
    c.MessageGroupId as MessageGroupId,
    b.QueuedTime as QueuedTime
into table_1
from   [EAC].[MessageStore].[MessageProcessingAttemptState] a 
    inner JOIN [EAC].[MessageStore].[MessageProcessingAttempt]  b
        ON a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID = b.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID
    inner join [EAC].[MessageStore].[Message] c
        on b.MessageID = c.MessageID


select t.Queued, t.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID
from table_1 t
where MessageProcessingAttemptStateID = '1'
    and MessageGroupId = '44'
    and QueuedTime BETWEEN '2014-09-12' AND '2014-09-16'

select t.Queued, t.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID
from table_1 t
where MessageProcessingAttemptStateID = '2'
    and MessageGroupId = '44'
    and QueuedTime BETWEEN '2014-09-12' AND '2014-09-16'
```

It would work faster because instead of doing this

```
from   [EAC].[MessageStore].[MessageProcessingAttemptState] a 
    inner JOIN [EAC].[MessageStore].[MessageProcessingAttempt]  b
        ON a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID = b.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID
    inner join [EAC].[MessageStore].[Message] c
        on b.MessageID = c.MessageID
```

four times, the compiler would do it once. Also, it's much more readable and the differences are easier to spot.

Note: To some it would be trivial, but just in case note that you don't need to have table_1 in your database. In fact you should not have a table in your database named table_1. If you do, just change table_1 in this query to some other name. If you wonder why then it's pretty simple. When you use this type of syntax, the compiler creates a table named table_1 that has the same columns that you are trying to insert and those columns are of the same datatype.

Edit:
Come to think of it, after you run for the first time change this

```
select count(STATENAME)as Queued,
    a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID as MessageProcessingAttemptStateID,
    c.MessageGroupId as MessageGroupId,
    b.QueuedTime as QueuedTime
into table_1
```

into

```
insert into table_1
select count(STATENAME)as Queued,
        a.MessageProcessingAttemptStateID as MessageProcessingAttemptStateID,
        c.MessageGroupId as MessageGroupId,
        b.QueuedTime as QueuedTime
```

Comment: results are not proper

Comment: @user2183213 what does that mean?